# C: Error in Using: "Compound Assignment" and "Prefix Decrement" together

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors, compound-assignment, prefix-operator

Can someone please tell me why the `C` compiler outputs an error while using a `Compound Assignment` and a `Prefix Dec/Inc` together ? [ but `C++` does not ]

```
int myVar = 5;
(--myVar) -= 4;
// C  : error C2106: '-=' : left operand must be l-value
// C++: myVar=0;
```

I know what the error says ...

But, I can't understand **why a `C` compiler can't recognize `myVar` as a l-value** but `C++` does?!

Comment: myVar is lvalue, --myVal is not lvalue, simple as that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C, prefix `--` operator yields an rvalue. An rvalue can't be a left operand of  assignment operator. That said, C and C++ are two different languages.

Comment: assignment would be more specific, since there are quite a few ways to assign into integer